# Sanitize HTML5 with PHP (prevent XSS)

Tags: php, html, xss, wysiwyg, sanitize

I'm building WYSIWYG editor with HTML5 and Javascript.
I'll allow users post pure HTML via WYSIWYG, so it have to be sanitized.

Basic task like protecting site from cross site scripting (XSS) is coming difficult task, because there isn't up-to-date purify & filter -software for PHP.

**HTML Purifier** isn't support HTML5 at the moment and overall status looks very bad (HTML5 support isn't coming anytime soon).

So how should I sanitize untrusted HTML5 with PHP (backend) ?

Options so far...

- HTML Purifier (lack of new HTML5 tags, data-attributes etc.)
- Implementing own purifier with strip_tags() and Tidy or PHP's DOM classes/functions
- Using some "random" Tidy implementations like http://eksith.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/whitelist-html-sanitizing-with-php/
- Google Caja (Javascript / Cloud)
- htmLawed (there's beta for HTML5 support)

Is there any other options out there? Is PHP dying? ;)

Comment: You prevent cross site scripting with csrf tokens. Any decent framework will provide a simple implementation. If you choose to be a cowboy and roll your own, it's work, but please don't complain about php dying.

Comment: I already have CSRF protection, but it is not enough protection. Users could still post (inject) JS events, CSS styles etc. without proper sanitization. There must be white-list for allowed HTML5 tags and attributes. That PHP is dying part was a (bad?) joke.

Comment: Post css styles? You're not making much sense, son.

Comment: <p class="mainmenu"><p> **OR** <div style="height: 100000px;"></div>

Comment: @pguardiario — CSRF and XSS are completely different kinds of attack (and while CSRF protection will usually defeat reflected XSS attacks, it won't help much against stored XSS attacks)

Comment: @stacknoob — What's wrong with just [adding elements and attributes](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) from HTML 5 that you want to allow to the whitelist?

Comment: @Quentin How about <canvas>, data-attributes and changing <br /> to <br> etc. - Basic <article> etc. could be doable task.

Comment: @stacknoob — Canvas is just an element, so you could add it (why you would want to allow it as user input, I have no idea), I doubt it is easy to allow arbitrary `data-` attributes, but since they are explicitly for local site extensions to HTML anyway that doesn't matter, you just add the specific data attributes you care about. In HTML 5 `<br />` and `<br>` are equivalent, so changing between them doesn't matter. Allowing `<article>` should be trivial, but I'm having trouble imagining a point where you would be asking for user input that consists of multiple articles at once.

Comment: @Quentin You're right. Specifically in my case, I'll only need few data-attributes and all needed tags are found from HTML 4.01 / XHTML. But it doesn't remove the fact that we don't have proper HTML5 purifier for PHP, at the moment. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

PHP offers parsing methods to protect from code PHP/SQL injections (i.e. `mysql_real_escape_string()`). This is not the case for HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Why that?

First: HTML/CSS/Javascript sole purpose is to display information. It is pretty much up to you to accept certain elements of HTML or reject them depending of your requirements.

Secondly: due to the very high number of HTML/CSS/JS elements (also increasing constantly), it is impossible to try to control HTML. you cannot expect a functional solution.

This is why I would suggest a top-down solution. **I suggest to start restricting everything and then only allowing a certain number of tags.** One good base is probably to use [BBCdode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode), pretty popular. If you want to "unlock" additional specific tags beyond BBCode, you can always add some.

This is the reason BBCode-like scripts are popular on forums and websites (including stack overflow). WISIGIG editors are designed for admin/internal use, because you don't expect your website administrator to inject bad content.

bottom-top approaches are vowed to fail. HTML sanitizers are exposed to exponential complexity and do not guarantee anything.

---

### **EDIT 1**

---

You say it is a sanitation problem, not a front end issue. I disagree, because as you cannot handle all present and future HTML entities you would better restrict it at a front end level to be 100% sure.

This said, perhaps the below is a working solution for you:

1. you can do a bit to sanitize your code by **striping all entities
   except those in a white list** using PHP's `strip_tags()`.
2. You can also **remove all remaining tags attributes** (properties)
   by using PHP's `preg_replace()` with some regular expression.

---

```
$string = "put some very dirty HTML here.";
$string = strip_tags($string, '<p><a><span><h1><li><ul><br>');
$string = preg_replace("/<([b-z][b-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $string);
echo $string;
```

---

**This will return your sanitized text.**

*note : I have excluded attributes removal for  tags because you may still want to keep href="" properties. hence the `[b-z][B-Z]` regex.*

Comment: Besides, there are a few good editors on the market, all turnkey: CKEditor or TinyMCE editor etc. Why not use them?

Comment: WYSIWYG is better for this user base. I know they don't want to learn coding language/syntax, like BBCode. HTMLPurifier's (and similar) point is that it restrict everything and then only allow a certain number of tags. I need only few tags, like bold and italic, so CKEditor and TinyMCE would be overkill for this.

Comment: Problem is sanitization, not frontend implementation or escaping database queries.

Answer (score -1):

I Believe the ideal is to use a combination :

```
  mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['data']));
```

On Write

and

```
   stripslashes($data)
```

on read always did the trick for me, I think it is better than

```
  htmentities($data) on write
```

and

```
  html_entity_decode($data) on read
```