# How to sanitize post but allow special country names

Tags: php

I'm using countries list from [REST COUNTRIES](https://restcountries.eu/).

I am trying to sanitize my post, but I need special latin chars and single quotes to be allowed because "REST COUNTRIES" API provides some names with non-English letters and single-quote such as "Côte d'Ivoire"

Comment: What's the specific problem you've encountered?  Why are any of those characters an issue?

Comment: Please give us some piece of code responsible for taking care of countries names. :)

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455434/sanitize-html5-with-php-prevent-xss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455434/sanitize-html5-with-php-prevent-xss)